# The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it. Django serilizer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

this is my code

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=255)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_filename_brand_image)  #over write
    add_to_explore = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model): 
    brand = models.ForeignKey('core.Brand', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True ,blank=True)


class ItemSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     brand_logo = serializers.CharField(source='brand.logo.url')

class Meta:
    model = Item
    fields = ['id','brand_logo']
```

if image None I got this erorr
The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.

How to handel this erorr

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to check image field have file or not. For example;

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class ItemSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    brand_logo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['id', 'brand_logo']

    def get_brand_logo(self, obj):
        return obj.brand.logo and obj.brand.logo.url or None
```

If brand has logo then simply returns it's url otherwise returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

Here `get_brand_logo()` return image if the image provided `else` return `None`

```
class ItemSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    brand_logo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['id', 'brand_logo']

    def get_brand_logo(self, obj):
        if obj.brand.logo:
            return obj.brand.logo.url
        else:None
```